# Titanium Studio won't recognize V8 Android?

Tags: android, titanium

Every time I try to run a program as a V8 Android in Titanium Studio, I get the following error message:

```
This launch uses a V8 Android Runtime, which require Android 2.2 SDK and above. 
Please edit your launch configuration to select a compatible SDK.
```

I could run it as a Rhino program, but if possible, I would like the added speed of the V8 engine. I am trying to run the program as an Android 2.2, and I have the latest SDK. Any idea what's going on?

tiapp.xml (Slightly stripped down)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ti:app xmlns:ti="http://ti.appcelerator.org">
    <deployment-targets>
        <target device="mobileweb">true</target>
        <target device="iphone">false</target>
        <target device="ipad">false</target>
        <target device="android">true</target>
        <target device="blackberry">false</target>
    </deployment-targets>
    <sdk-version>2.1.4.GA</sdk-version>
    <publisher>pearsonartphoto</publisher>
    <icon>appicon.png</icon>
    <persistent-wifi>false</persistent-wifi>
    <prerendered-icon>false</prerendered-icon>
    <statusbar-style>default</statusbar-style>
    <statusbar-hidden>false</statusbar-hidden>
    <fullscreen>false</fullscreen>
    <navbar-hidden>false</navbar-hidden>
    <analytics>true</analytics>
    <property name="ti.ui.defaultunit">system</property>
    <iphone>
        <orientations device="iphone">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
        </orientations>
        <orientations device="ipad">
            <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
            <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
        </orientations>
    </iphone>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
    <mobileweb>
        <precache/>
        <splash>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <inline-css-images>true</inline-css-images>
        </splash>
        <theme>default</theme>
    </mobileweb>
    <modules>
        <module platform="commonjs" version="2.3.0">ti.cloud</module>
    </modules>
</ti:app>
```

My config:

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Latest Android SDK (Rev 21 with API 17) 64 Bit
- Titanium Studio 2.1.4 GA

Comment: Is your tiapp.xml set to 2.1.4 SDK? `<sdk-version>2.1.4.GA</sdk-version>`

Comment: `<sdk-version>2.1.4.GA</sdk-version>` Check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Titanium Studio, Go into Run->Run Configurations...

From the list of Android Emulator projects, find the project having the problem and highlight it.  On the right side, make sure the Android API is at least version 2.2 or higher.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had met with the same issue and I solved it through the following steps

1. Go To your Titanium Preferences (Window -> Preferences).
2. Select the Titanium option as given in the picture.
3. Set default Android SDK to **Google APIs Android 2.2**
4. Select your screen size
5. Press ok
6. Restart the Titanium studio
7. Run your application with android emulator

[image: Titanium android settings]

*If it doesn't solved your problem, please check your android SDK*

1. Go to your andorid sdk location ( eg: C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk)
2. Open AVD Manager
3. Create a new Virtual Device
4. Select the target Device as Android 2.2 API Level 8
5. Try your new virtual device